# In DosBox-X batch, how to get user string input?

Tags: batch-file, dos, dosbox

I need a text input in Dosbox, so it goes into an enviroment variable.

None of the solutions on Stack Overflow worked. `set /p` doesn't work. W.bat doesn't work too. I can use other programs besides the default in command.com.

Comment: Welcome to actual, honest-to-god pre-NT DOS. There's no user input; just hardcode the values into the script manually and then update the script when the values need to change. (There's a reason nobody uses this anymore if they don't have to.) You can try the techniques used [here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php#DOS) but I don't have DOSBox installed so I can't confirm if they work.

Comment: @SomethingDark I'm not stranger to DOS, I'm just not used to actually scripting something useful and not a shortcut. :D Thank you for your comment though, I will try it out!

Comment: @SomethingDark Doesn't do what I want sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `strings` utility. It worked perfectly for me:

```
strings variableName= ASK Question:
```

You can download it by using [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20000914073439/http://2dos.homepage.dk/batutil/strings.zip) from Internet Archive.